# How do I test with JMockit setAttribute in session object?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jmockit

I have the following problem, I have tried testing with JMockit, and everything works fine until I test the following line:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("property", new Object ());
```

shown me the problem is as follows:

> > mockit.internal.UnexpectedInvocation: Parameter 1 of javax.servlet.http.HttpSession #     setAttribute (String, Object) java.lang.Object@1d10f4e expected, got java.lang.Object@69e70e6c 
> >     at pac.con.servlets.Transfer.defaultAction (transfer.java: 69) 
> >     at pac.con.servlets.transfer.TransferTests.testTransfer (TransferTests.java: 110) 
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method) 
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java: 606) 
> >     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run (JUnit4TestReference.java: 50) 
> >     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run (TestExecution.java: 38) 
> >     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests (RemoteTestRunner.java: 467) 
> >     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests (RemoteTestRunner.java: 683) 
> >     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run (RemoteTestRunner.java: 390) 
> >     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main (RemoteTestRunner.java: 197)

in my test, I try to set that object as follows:

```
request.getSession (); returns (session); 
session.setAttribute ("property", new Object ());
```

Greetings and thanks